# Delete some characters from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm quite new to manipulate dataframes in R. I need to create a dataframe by joining several other ones, each containing some data.
I've succeeded in joining them, but I got that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkFDg.png

And what I want is a clean dataframe, so I would like to remove the , " " and $ characters in order to obtain a "real" dataframe. Can you help me with that? Many thanks!

PS: I'm using *dplyr* and *statsr* libraries, don't know if this onformation is useful though...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: The clean dataframe I want: [link](https://imgur.com/a/7GZ69LH)

Comment: Hey there. Have a look at the link I commented above.  We need the examples to be reproducible. Usually we do that via `dput()`

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like comma separated format (csv). The simplest way would probably be to save it as plain text and read the file with `csv.get`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Jan, the best way is to read-in the data more fittingly. If, for some reason, this is not a viable option, then this might work:

First off, some illustrative data:

```
v1 <- c(',"Name","Area","Population"')
v2 <- c(',"Afghanistan",652230,32564342')
v3 <- c(',"Akrotiri",123,NA"')
v4 <- c(',"Albania",28748,3029278')

df1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(v1,v2,v3,v4))
df1
                               V1
v1    ,"Name","Area","Population"
v2 ,"Afghanistan",652230,32564342
v3            ,"Akrotiri",123,NA"
v4       ,"Albania",28748,3029278
```

The first step is (i) to get rid of the leading comma and the quote marks using `gsub`, (ii) split the rows at the comma using `strsplit`, (iii) to save the result as a dataframe using `as.data.frame`, and (iv) to transpose it using `t`:

```
df2 <- t(as.data.frame(apply(df1, 2, function(x) strsplit(trimws(gsub('^,|"', '', x)),","))))
```

The rest is rather cosmetic: first remove the row names, then add the correct column names, and finally remove the first row (which contains the names too):

```
rownames(df2) <- NULL   
colnames(df2) <- df2[1,]
df3 <- as.data.frame(df2[-1,])
```

The result is a neat and clean structure:

```
df3
         Name   Area Population
1 Afghanistan 652230   32564342
2    Akrotiri    123         NA
3     Albania  28748    3029278
```